# Uncaught type error is not a function reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I get uncaught type error canvas_resize() is not a function. Below is the code snippet,

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        this.canvas_resize();
        this.start_drawing();
    });
canvas_resize = () => {
    const canvas_holder = this.canvas_holder_ref.current;
    const new_width = canvas_holder.clientWidth;
    const new_height = canvas_holder.clientHeight;
    const canvas = canvas_holder.children[0];
    canvas.width = new_width;
    canvas.height = new_height;
    canvas.style.width = new_width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = new_height + 'px';
};
```

I am not sure why I get the uncaught type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function has to be declared outside lifecycle method.  Also, use arrow function to access **this** inside a function. You will have a scope when you use arrow function

```
canvas_resize = () => {
    const canvas_holder = this.canvas_holder_ref.current;
    const new_width = canvas_holder.clientWidth;
    const new_height = canvas_holder.clientHeight;
    const canvas = canvas_holder.children[0];
    canvas.width = new_width;
    canvas.height = new_height;
    canvas.style.width = new_width + 'px';
    canvas.style.height = new_height + 'px';
};

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        this.canvas_resize();
        this.start_drawing();
    });
}
```

OR

```
componentDidMount() {
    const that = this;
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
        that.canvas_resize();
        that.start_drawing();
    });
}
```

But I would recommend you to use arrow function instead of referring this to a local variable inside a function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/j43r4o457v